# Else statement not executing in PHP condition

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have an if/else condition in a PHP function that sets the status of a submitted form. If the form already exists, then the form ID is stored as a session variable and that tells the function which form to update. If the form is brand new, then the form ID does not exist as a session variable and the ELSE statement should execute. The code is written to retrieve the last record in the database in the case of a new form.

```
//Set the form status
if(isset($_SESSION['formId']))
{
//Update the status of the EXISTING record
$setStat = $con->prepare("UPDATE table SET Status = :status WHERE
    formID = :formid");
$data = array('status'=>$status,'formid'=>$_SESSION['formId']);
$setStat -> execute($data);
}

else
{
//Update the status of the NEWLY CREATED record
$id = $con->prepare("SELECT TOP 1 formID FROM table ORDER BY formID 
    DESC");
$id->execute();
$row = $id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$formId = $row['formID'];

$setStatNew = $con->prepare("UPDATE table SET Status = :status WHERE 
    formID = :formid");
$data2 = array('status'=>$status,'formid'=>$formId);
$setStatNew -> execute($data2);
}
```

The function is called after the new record gets written, and I've been able to confirm that, in the case of a new form, the form id session variable is NOT set and that the query to retrieve the newest record from the DB works. I can successfully echo out the newest form ID. The ELSE statement never executes, however. When a new form is submitted, the status remains NULL. What could I be missing?

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); at the top to see what actually have in it

Comment: Use `vardump($_SESSION)` to examine your `$_SESSION` variable and figure out what's going on

Comment: I think it always set $_SESSION['formId']. since you have stored it in session.

Comment: Is `session_start();` in all your pages? If not, then your conditional statement(s) won't work. I ask this, because I don't see it in your posted code. Plus, I assume that `table` is under another name?

Comment: Yes, session_start() is on all of my pages. There's no problem with the function when the session variable is set. It's just the else statement that doesn't work. Also, when I echo the session variable in the case of a new form, it doesn't exist, which is how it should be.

Comment: Instead of the `else` can you try `if(!isset($_SESSION['formId']))` or `if(!isset($_SESSION))` ? This is too weird. You may need to assign a session variable in your `else`, which is another option.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Just tried that. No joy. Seems like it *should* work, though.

Comment: Can you try something deliberate? If you can make it go to the `else` statement, put in an `echo "OK, this should work";` and see if that echoes out. If it does, yet the rest doesn't continue, then something in there is breaking your code. You need to go about it step by step.

Comment: Seconding Fred's most recent comment. echoing out something to indicate you made it into the else is a good step to debug it.

Comment: By the way, I found this piece of info: "SELECT TOP is used for SQL-Server, not for MySQL" Are you on SQL or MySQL server?

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'm getting into the else statement, but the code is not executing properly. Nothing obvious is leaping out at me.

This is a SQL Server database I'm working with, hence the SELECT TOP.

Comment: Ok, good. So now we know that the `else` does in fact work. It's what's after, that's not kicking in for some reason.

Comment: Exactly. I'm also able to successfully echo the last form ID in the same else statement, so I know that's okay. Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: Can you try removing `ORDER BY formID 
    DESC` ?

Comment: Actually, I just figured out that $status isn't showing up in the else statement, hence the NULLs. $status is set by a switch() statement that executes before this condition. I'll research that next. Odd, because it shows up fine when the form ID already exists.

Comment: Also, if you're assigning a session name from a POST variable (which I don't see in your code) i.e.: `$_SESSION['formId'] = $_POST['formId'];` then you will need to include that in your `else` statement.

Comment: You can also troubleshoot it a bit more by putting `var_dump($_SESSION);` in the `else` condition to see if a session is set, because I sense that you're using the session name `formId` to be used for the query and since it's not in your `else` then it can't use it because it doesn't exist and is not being created. You can also use `var_dump($_SESSION['formId']);` also. That's the best I can do to help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont call

```
session_start();
```

session do not work!

my idea is

```
if($_SESSION['formId']=="submit")
{
    //your code
}
else
{
     // your code
    $_SESSION['formId']="submit";
}
```

Comment: [As previously stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029504/else-statement-not-executing-in-php-condition#comment31612679_21029504) --- I **never** post an answer before I get to know the whole picture. Call it "experience" ;-)